# How to put a link in a Google map marker's snippet

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to link a website and (hopefully) a phone number into a snippet of a map marker that I am creating on my map. Is there anyway to do this? If not, what is another way I could possibly display something above the clicked marker that contains a clickable website and a clickable phone number. I was thinking an Alert Dialog but I do not know how to set up onClickListeners for **dynamically** made map markers.

```
public void addWayPointMarkers(LatLng point){
    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions();
    marker.title(name);
    marker.snippet(Html.fromHtml(address + "<br />" + phone + "<br />" + "<a href=\"" + website + "\">Website</a>"));       
    marker.position(point);

    map.addMarker(marker);
}
```

Comment: the link will not be clickable in the info window

Comment: My question is if there is anyway to make it clickable. If not, can you suggest another approach?

Comment: I made a Marker ArrayList and everytime a marker is clicked, I compared that marker with the markers in the ArrayList. All that needs to be done is to have the class implement OnMarkerClickListener

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the link to be clickable, this will not work

`The info window that is drawn is not a live view. The view is rendered as an image (using View.draw(Canvas)) at the time it is returned. This means that any subsequent changes to the view will not be reflected by the info window on the map. To update the info window later (e.g., after an image has loaded), call showInfoWindow(). Furthermore, the info window will not respect any of the interactivity typical for a normal view such as touch or gesture events. However you can listen to a generic click event on the whole info window as described in the section below.`

you can however show a dialog with the information if you like when the marker is clicked

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible for you show an example on how to show a dialog with the code I provided?

Comment: its just like any other dialog, look up dialogs on the developer website. you are probably going to have to store the information in an `HashMap` with the marker id as the key and the information as the content

Comment: How do I give a marker an ID if I am creating it dynamically as shown in the code above?

Comment: `map.addMarker(marker);` returns a marker, get the id from it